# How to Image OS X's Memory

Tags: macos, memory, ram, imaging, computer-forensics

so I am taking a Computer Forensics class (also hoping to go into Computer Forensics, so the practice helps).  In my class we have to do a research project.  I am doing it on Kali specifically with RAM Forensics and Web Browser Forensics.  I am trying to use Volatility to take a look at my RAM but I need an image of my RAM first to read from.  Does anyone know a way of imaging the RAM on an OS X?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OS X used to have a /dev/mem device you could just read to read out physical memory, but they removed that a while back. Amit Singh's [Mac OS X Internals](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164014/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter8/kma/) book has a section on implementing a kernel extension to add that interface back in. There are various open-source implementations of the same idea out there, but I don't have direct experience with them.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll take a look at that.  Kind of weird to add a kernel that makes the computer less secure to forensics... haha

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly the FTK Imager can get osx ram image but you can try it.
It can get image of the ram from windows operating system. In my opinion it also get the image of the ram from osx system.